# Is it possible to specify which javac command to use in a Leiningen project?

Tags: java, clojure, javac, leiningen

I have a project in which I want to use a different javac than the machine default.
The java-cmd at the project level seems to override the default java but not the default javac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an environment variable `LEIN_JAVA_CMD` that can override both.